# No internet connection using ethernet

Tags: internet

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 as an app in Windows 7. I got internet but after updating it and restarting it, there is no Internet. it shows that it is connected to **Wired connection 1** but no Internet.

Comment: You said UBUNTU installed as an app in win7. Do you want to say you install it using wubi installer or in virtual machine like virtualbox or vmware.

please clear the way of your installation?

Answer (score 0):

Are your proxy settings correct?
Check it from

```
System Settings>Network>Network proxy
```

Comment: No need of any proxy to connect to Network

Comment: Ok, are your network settings correct?...I mean IP settings?.
Try pinging www.google.com

Comment: Beyond pinging other servers, you can get information on your IP settings by choosing "Connection info..." from the network panel menu or by entering `ifconfig` into a terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

if it is a dsl connection with username and password , you will have to set in "edit connection" in the network manager drop down menu. previously you may have connected through windows and then installed ubuntu, so it was working, now you will have to set it separately for ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the firewall and see if that fixes it. "sudo ufw disable" if it does then configure it correctly (google it) don't just leave it disabled!